# Is it possible to have an element's opacity carry through other elements to the background; like a window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

I was imagining having boxes with a fixed position start at the bottom of the page over the background. Their opacity is set at .8 and they will stay fixed to the bottom of the page until they are scrolled onto the white background further down the page. Even though they're passing over this new white background, I still want to see the original background through the boxes as they scroll over the white. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Have you looked into the opacity property or using RGBA as the background color in CSS?

Comment: It is possible but there would be a lot of hacks involved. It isnt possible purely in CSS. You will need to use javascript also.

Comment: @coopersita I haven't in depth but I will now that you said that. Didn't think it would be possible just using CSS.

Comment: @Anubhav Could you give me a rough outline of the process I would need to use to achieve this? Or at the very least a way to find it via google? I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: Sounds something like the ["Mozart" design](http://www.csszengarden.com/189/) over on Zen Garden - which is pure CSS, no javascript.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Not quite. The "window" element will pass over 2 different backgrounds. I want the white background to essentially disappear when the "window" element passes over it, sustaining line of sight to the back most fixed background. Hard to explain without a visualization.

Comment: Yeah, I think I would need to see an annotated image or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[For a non-fixed non-scaled background image]**

If I'm understanding correctly, the effect you are looking for is basically for the boxes to show a view through the white boxes and display the background of the page.  While this can't actually be done with just css, it can be simulated with javascript.

The basic idea is to set the background of the boxes to the same background as the page and then adjust their background positions to match their location on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/o6z18o7e/1

```js
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".box").each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var pos = $this.offset();
            
            $this.css("background-position", (pos.left * -1) + "px " + (pos.top * -1) + "px");
        });
    }).scroll();
});
```

```css
body{
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/3000);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box{
    border: 3px solid gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/3000);
}
.content-box{
    margin-top: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" style="top: 50px; left: 100px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="top: 175px; left: 150px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="top: 450px; left: 300px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="top: 50px; left: 600px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="top: 350px; left: 650px;"></div>

<div class="content-box"></div>
<div class="content-box"></div>
<div class="content-box"></div>
<div class="content-box"></div>
<div class="content-box"></div>
<div class="content-box"></div>
```

Comment: "... then adjust their background positions to match their location on the page" - is that not what CSS [background-attachment:fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) does?

Comment: I need to look into that a bit more to see if there's a way around it, but it doesn't seem to update on scroll for fixed elements:  http://jsfiddle.net/o6z18o7e/2/

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand the requirement better ... maybe "apparent hole through scrolling layer" would describe it?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I tried it out in my own project and it didn't have the desired effect though. I don't know why the picture on jsfiddle isn't scrolling but on my site, it looks like my jsfiddle example but it scrolls through the repeated background on user scroll. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/trunks470/6feraj7p/1/

Comment: Also, if I just wanted to have a box with standard positioning still have this effect, what would I need to do?

Comment: I have added a separate answer related to the new information gained from looking at your fiddle.  I would suggest you add the fiddle as well as additional information into your question.  It is important to note that your body's background is fixed as well as scaled.  These two bits of information make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding a separate answer here because I believe the first may be useful to others, so I'd rather not remove it.  However, in comments the requirements of the question were further refined.

**[For a fixed background]**

With the background position of the body's background being fixed, it is actually much simpler.  You can simply add an inner div that has the same background properties as the body.  Pure css, no js needed.  It even works with background scaling with window size.

http://jsfiddle.net/6feraj7p/3/

```css
body, .bg {
 background: url('http://www.junoon.co/sw-store/images/wallpapers/urdu.co-34163121.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size:cover;
 -o-background-size:cover;
 background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.longBox {
 height: 100vh;
 margin-top: 100vh;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 background-size: 100%;
 margin-right: -3000px;
 padding-right: 3000px;
 margin-left:  -3000px;
 padding-left:  3000px;
}
#propertyButton {
 bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 background-size: 100%;
 position: fixed;
}
.button{
    border: 3px solid gray;
    height: 35vh;
 width: 35vh;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bg{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "propertyButton" class = "button"><div class="bg"></div></div>
<div class = "longBox"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I suppose my comment was a different question but as these are so closely related I thought it would be appropriate to have both displayed on the same page. This answer works flawlessly, however the other doesn't when I applied specifications to it. I will fiddle around with it on my own because it's obviously my own errors which are breaking it. Thank you for your time! Cheers!